# pg_upgrade arguments order

Tags: postgresql

This isn't really a question since I've figured out the answer, but I didn't find it documented *anywhere* else so I'm putting it here.

I attempted to use pg_upgrade with the -c (check-only) and -k (hard links) options (not at the same time), but it consistently ignored them both.  After much searching and trial, error, and hair loss, I finally figured out this nugget - they have to be the first argument (or at least before the ones I used) for them to be applied.

These seem to work:

```
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade -c --old-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data" --new-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/12/data" --old-bindir "/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin" --new-bindir "/usr/pgsql-12/bin"
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade -k --old-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data" --new-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/12/data" --old-bindir "/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin" --new-bindir "/usr/pgsql-12/bin"
```

These do **NOT**:

```
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data" --new-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/12/data" --old-bindir "/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin" --new-bindir "/usr/pgsql-12/bin" -c
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data" --new-datadir "/var/lib/pgsql/12/data" --old-bindir "/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin" --new-bindir "/usr/pgsql-12/bin" -k
```

OS: CentOS 6.6

Comment: Works for me, with both set of binaries compiled and installed myself.  How did you install?

Comment: Didn't compile myself; installed the standard package via yum and the default pgdg repo.